# "Dynamically" generated x and y values of a subview's frame depending on the width/height of a view "element" above it?

Tags: ios, uikit

Is there a way to set the x and y values of a subview's frame depending on the width and height of another subview that's above it? In other words, by an example, let's say a UIView has two subviews, a UILabel and a UIImage, the content of the label might change in the future and take up more space (two or three "lines" instead of one) -  what would I have to do to make that image be displayed slightly lower depending on the number of characters used in that label? Is there an alternative for simply using a UIWebView?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What is your problem at setting x and y of this view?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using UITextView to label your UIImage.  There is a delegate method - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView in the UITextView Delegate (UITextViewDelegate).  This fires when the text view changes so you can check the content size in the text view then and move the image if necessary.

You can implement this to check if the textview.contentSize.height + y coordinate is larger then the UIImage y coordinate and then if so move the UIImage to a new offset for the y coordinate.  Same thing with the textview.contentSize.width + X coordinate and the UIIMage x coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Views shouldn't really set their own frame x and y because, as you have described, the appropriate values depend on context which the individual view has no knowledge of.

You want to implement `layoutSubviews` in the containing view to appropriately size and position the label and image views. Then when you detect that say the size of the label has changed you call `setNeedsLayout` on the containing view. This will tell UIKit that the containing view's subviews need to be sized and positioned again and your implementation of `layoutSubviews` will get called at the appropriate time.